# TabLayout - underline невыбранной вкладки android 4.1.1 (16 api)

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

Заметил такую проблему на андройде 4.1.1 с отображением underline у невыбранной вкладки:

**Как это выглядит на 4.2.2 (api 17):**

[image: Как это выглядит на 4.2.2 (api 17)]

**Как это выглядит на 4.1.1 (api 16):**

[image: Как это выглядит на 4.1.1 (api 16)]

То есть по идее должна отрисоваться тонкая линия серого цвета, но андройд мало того, что игнорирует ее, так еще и закрашивает вообще весь tablayout **черным** цветом.

**Линию сделал данным способом:**

У свойства app:tabBackground указал xml файл со следующим содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" >
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/colorGrey1" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorGrey5"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

**Также попробовал и вот этот способ:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/shl_common_default_color" />
        <size android:height="1.5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Но все по-прежнему также, решения данной проблемы не нашел, заранее спасибо :\

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы окрасить фон, используйте свойство `background`

```
android:background="#333"
```

Для того полоски не нужен никакой свой `drawable`

ваш вариант легко заменяется свойствами `tabIndicatorHeight` и `tabIndicatorColor`

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="1.5dp"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/shl_common_default_color"
```

Невыбранному табу не нужна своя полоска

сделайте серую полоску всему `TabLayout`, область под выбранным табом будет закрываться родным индикатором.

Comment: app:tabIndicatorColor отвечает только за линию выбранной вкладки, в моем случае у меня стоит app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/green", речь же идет о линии для невыбранной вкладки, просьба читать вопрос внимательнее :)

Comment: @SWR обновил ответ

Comment: так мне нужна эта полоска :/ это часть дизайна, дабы отделить от контента

Comment: Контент будет отделен серой полоской, которая будет применена ко всему `TabLayout`